# I recently added a folder to my class library, now I get an error "the type or namespace cannot be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know this is probably something stupid-simple, but I recently added a folder to my Models project and placed all of my models in there.  Once I did that, I get an error saying "the type or namespace 'filler' cannot be found in CapWorx.QuikCap.Models".  As expected, because I moved 'filler' to a new location.  I placed 'filler' in CapWorx.QuikCap.Models.Data.  Here's the error:

[image]

I get the error when I click the filler item on my page and the page is supposed to go to the Edit form for that item: here's what my Edit method looks like in my controller.  Keep in mind though that I never get any errors in the code when stepping through it.  In fact, if I hover over "filler", it will show me all of the properties, which is what's supposed to be shown on the NEXT screen (Edit), but I get the error.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int cappk)
    {
        filler filler = db.fillers.Find(id);
        if (filler == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.capsule_fk = new SelectList(db.capsules, "pk", "name", filler.capsule_fk);
        return View(filler);
    }
```

I've already updated my using statements to `using CapWorx.QuikCap.Models.Data`, from `using CapWorx.QuikCap.Models`.

Is there some sort of caching going on that's retaining the old location?  Here's a screen-shot of my CapWorx.QuikCap.Models project, below.  'filler' is defined in DataModel.edmx:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting this error/warning? In your view (the yellow text at top)? In other C# code?

Comment: Funny thing is, it's a runtime error, but my code is able to be stepped through without fault.  Hope this helps.  Here's the error:


System.Web.HttpCompileExceptionc:\Users\mmarks1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5df0f055\661d3aad\App_Web_edit.cshtml.94004f3e.a9coj_4l.0.cs(30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'filler' does not exist in the namespace 'CapWorx.QuikCap.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: OIC, filler was a model, but is now an Entity... Definitely not caching. Please share the Controller that raises the exception... or is it a build error?

Comment: thats 2012, so i assume you're using a code generation device. Do you see an actual object filler there?

Comment: I've updated my question Dave to include the controller.  It's not actually throwing any exceptions in the code, which is weird.  It gets the filler object just fine along with all of its properties.

Comment: i find this line to be interesting because the type of filler is not the type of the entity: filler filler = db.fillers.Find(id);

Comment: I'm declaring a variable (of type 'filler') called 'filler'.  This was an "out of the box" implementation.

Comment: Is this a web site "project" (created with File->New Web Site) or a web application project (created with File->New Project)? I never use web site "projects" for anything non-trivial.

Comment: adding a reference is one thing but this sounds like a namespace issue can you show the namespace of the class you have in the new folder..?

Comment: John- this is a web app project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the Edit view for my filler object (which is what the app was trying to go to before it threw this error) declared an incorrect reference to my filler object at the top of the page.  Before, this is what the top of my page looked like:

```
@model CapWorx.QuikCap.Models.filler

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Existing Filler";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Then, I changed it to:

```
@model CapWorx.QuikCap.Models.Data.filler

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Existing Filler";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

And then, it worked.  This was something that could have easily been overlooked by most people because I wasn't getting any compile time errors, even though I had red squigglies on this page.  Thanks for all of the suggestions.